# How to Transpose Rows to Columns Towards Left Columns? In Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[SECOND IMAGE CLICK NUMBER 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjfnS.jpg)  I Want To Transpose Row Value Range A2:A50 To Column CZ2 To BC2. Formula Should Be Given IN CZ2. AND VALUE SHOULD GET IN REVERSE OR LEFT COLUMNS.[First IMAGE Click Number 2] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q6PH.jpg). If I Give Transpose (AO2:AO50) In CZ2 it Will go range from CZ2 To EW2.  **I Want Transpose in Reverse Columns**. If I Increase Row Value AO2:AO60 It Should Flow Towards Left From CZ2 To  AS2. I Mean Transpose Should work towards Left Side Columns. Its Ok with any other formula If Not Transpose. Hope My Question is Understandable. Someone Help Me Out. Thank You In Advance.

Comment: First of all, it looks very strange to try to change the logic of spreadsheets. If you need a formula, it can only be one of the array formulas - and they (since the history of Excel) can fill in data either from left to right or from top to bottom. I can suggest you use the following formula in cell `AP2` (but no way `CZ2`) `=transpose(index(sort({AO2:AO63,ROW(AO2:AO63)},2,false),,1))` Maybe it will do what you want. _PS. If you'll find possibility to write formula which will work in reverse direction - please inform me about it. It will be very useful for me. Thanks_

Comment: @Sergey, you may be interested in my proposed solution posted below.

Comment: "Hope My Question is Understandable"—it is not. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would want to do this. However, the end goal can be achieved by placing the following formula in cell B2 (not CZ2):

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(COLUMNS(B1:1)-COLUMN(B1:1)+ROW(A2)+1,{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,FALSE)))`

Try it and you'll see what I mean.

The formula is written to be flexible. So if you add or subtract data from A2:A, the value in A2 will always be in Row 2 of the last column to the right in the sheet; and all other values will work backward from there.

If you *always* want to start to backward progression in Column CZ *and* Column CZ is not (or may not always be) your rightmost column, you can use this version:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(COLUMN(CZ1)-COLUMN(B1:CZ1)+ROW(A2)+1,{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,FALSE)))`

Just understand that, if you don't have columns at least through Column CZ, this formula will fail to work as expected.

I recommend using the first formula I supplied above, since it will always work, no matter how many columns there are, filling backward as far as to the formula column (B2) as needed.

Understand also that if you have more than 103 rows of data in A2:A, that would be more than could fit between B2 and CZ2; so only the first 103 would be displayed.

**ADDENDUM** (*after reading first two comments below*):

The principle is the same if you want to run results from "CZ to BC"; only in this case, you want to limit the results to no more than 50.

Place the following formula in BC2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1,50,ROW(A2)+50-1,-1),{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,FALSE)))`

To reiterate, you cannot run formulas that will fill or columns backward. (Even if the sheet is set to right-to-left font with Column A appearing at the far right, the formula is still filling A-Z according to that setup.) However, if you know that you want a 50-column range reserved and you want the answers to go backward, this can still be achieved by placing the formula in the first of the 50 columns rather than the last, as I have proposed above.

Comment: Thank You For immediate Reply. Actually I Have A Date Column In DA And In DB I Have a Transpose Formula and That the Value goes from 50 To 100 Columns i,e from Column DB To  EY (50) or till GW(100)  I want to get those Columns value Sum from CZ to BA. And maximum 50 Column i want in Reverse Transpose. I want to use that Date Column. I don't know where it ends in Left side Columns and Again I Cant put Date in Left Side. Hope my words were understandable

Comment: I Have uploaded 2nd image . In Question (Second Image Click Number 1) Kindly Go through it. Hope it will make you Undrstand. Thank You

Comment: See my addendum to my post above.

Comment: I am Getting an ERROR , Formula Phrase Error. This Formula is not Working.ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1,50,ROW(A2)+50-1,-1),{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,FALSE))). Kindly give me any other formula where it works in reverse.

Comment: Rakesh, please understand that this forum and all others like it are run 100% by volunteers who donate free time as we are able, not by paid employees of a company. As such, the goal of these sites is to be a place where people can get a little information or help correcting a formula they've already tried. It is not a place where anyone can come to get time-intensive, customized solutions developed by experts at no cost. That said, the formula I provided works on my sheet. Share a link to a copy of your sheet, and I will take a quick look at it.

Comment: I am Extremely Sorry if My words were wrong. I Totally Agree this Site is meant for helping the people with existing formula or modification/Correction the  formula . I was wrong as I was demanding the solution  from your end. Well I have changed my mind I am taking Date value from DA Column In AZ and in BA I am applying Transpose. as normal towards Right Side. I will surely share my Sheet once it is completed. Thanks a ton for taking my words with patience and understanding me. I am Sorry Once Again.